# How to I avoid "group by" twice in a nested query

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, subquery

I am writing this query for the attributes with following relationship.

```
 State->City->Customer->Service Order.
```

All one-to-many. The subquery aggregate by grouping by `svc_ord_nbr` while the outer query does another aggregate on something else.

```
select state, city, cust_name, 
    count(distinct (case when start_date <> end_date then svc_ord_nbr end)) as not_fixed
    from
    (SELECT svc_ord_nbr, CUST_NAME,
        state, city,
        date_trunc('day', min(START_DTM)) as start_date,
        date_trunc('day', max(START_DTM)) as end_date
      FROM table a inner join...
            inner join....
    WHERE ......
    group by SVC_ORD_NBR, 
     cust_name,
     state, 
     city) q
     group by state, city, cust_name
```

In order to display state and city, it seems I have to group by them twice in both inner and outer query. I wonder if this is the best way to do it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff should've used `date_trunc`

Comment: `inner join....` ::please post the real query, not some meta-syntax.

Comment: You'll probably get better performance if your inner and outer group by operations have the columns listed in the same order with SVC_ORD_NBR last.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can avoid doing "2 layers" because you are calculating MIN/MAX by svc_ord_nbr then using those calculations for a subsequent count. You might be able simplify it a bit by only dealing with svc_ord_nbr in the inner layer e.g.

```
SELECT
      state
    , city
    , cust_name
    , COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN start_date <> end_date THEN svc_ord_nbr END)
            ) AS not_fixed
FROM (
      SELECT
            svc_ord_nbr
          , date_trunc('day', MIN(START_DTM)) AS start_date
          , date_trunc('day', MAX(START_DTM)) AS end_date
      FROM tablea a
      WHERE ......
      GROUP BY
            svc_ord_nbr
      ) q
inner join...
inner join....
GROUP BY
      state
    , city
    , cust_name
```

Answer (score 0):

One simplification that I can see is getting rid of the `count(distinct)` at the outer level.  Instead you can just do:

```
select state, city, cust_name, 
       sum((start_date <> end_date)::int) as not_fixed
. . .
```

There may be special cases where you can get rid of the two levels of aggregation, I can't think of a general solution.